# Wordpress style category widget

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, categories

I'm trying to find out how to style only the category widget. All widgets are using the same div names. Is there a code I can use to differentiate the category widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your theme should enclose widgets in some tag with a class unique to that widget. Look at the documentation for register_sidebar for how to specify the before_widget property to do so:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar

Failing that, if the widget doesn't have any unique selectors you can target, then you'll have to create them. If you're going to edit a built-in widget, I recommend copying its code into your functions.php rather than editing it in place, so that upgrading WordPress doesn't remove your modifications. Just register the widget with a different name.